# CTRun right to left on CoreText iOS

Tags: ios, core-text

I want to draw glyphs with `CGContextShowGlyphsAtPositions`, but when I use `CTRunGetPositions` the positions of the glyphs start from the left. The `CTRunGetStatus` returns `kCTRunStatusRightToLeft` but result the is left to right. How can I draw text from right to left?

For English characters left to right is ok because this language is left to right but I use arabic characters and arabic is a right to left language.

Answer (score 2):

The positions are left to right because the glyphs are generally drawn left to right since that's the direction that "x" increases in. By the time you're drawing a `CGGlyph`, the language doesn't matter any more. When drawing كتب, the system draws ب first, so its position comes first in the array.

The result of `CTRunGetGlyphs` is in the same order as `CTRunGetPositions`. All `kCTRunStatusRightToLeft` does is tell you that glyph order is strictly reverse of string index order.

I'm not having any trouble drawing Arabic right to left with `CGContextShowGlyphsAtPositions`. What problem are you seeing?

```
CFIndex glyphCount = CTRunGetGlyphCount(run);
CGPoint *positions = calloc(glyphCount, sizeof(CGPoint));
CTRunGetPositions(run, CFRangeMake(0, 0), positions);
CGGlyph *glyphs = calloc(glyphCount, sizeof(CGGlyph));
CTRunGetGlyphs(run, CFRangeMake(0, 0), glyphs);
CGContextShowGlyphsAtPositions(context, glyphs, positions, glyphCount);
free(positions);
free(glyphs);
```

Comment: tanx Rob this is about last line , when i create multiline line 1 or 2 is ok but last line drown on left , but in arabic last line must be drown on right .

Comment: First, do you have a strong reason to be using CGContextShowGlphysAtPositions() rather than CTFrameDraw() or CTLineDraw()? These should take care of that for you. Alternately, it's going to be up to you to adjust the drawing offset for each line.

Comment: No this is sample not release code , i using paragraph and it's ok and i create very well right to left paragraph but i want to manage glyph to change color of 1 or more glyph , and i meet this problem i use attributedstring but can't handle all of my want

Comment: You can't get what you want even if you map your glyphs back to your characters using `CTRunGetStringIndices()`? (This would let you work out that the glyph لا was originally the characters ل and ا for instance.) If you go all the way down to positions, then it's your problem to lay out the line correctly. You can look at `CTLineGetTrailingWhitespaceWidth()`, which will probably give you the offset you want to manage right-justification.

Comment: I use CTLineGetTrailingWhitespaceWidth() but it's always return 0.0

Comment: How are you generating your lines? Are you using a typesetter or a framesetter?

Comment: Rob i handle it with another way i use CTLineGetImageBounds to get line bound and then shift it to right side of view , it's okay now

Answer (score 1):

tanx Rob 
this is about last line , when i create multiline line 1 or 2 is ok but last line drown on left , but in arabic last line must be drown on right .

my Code is:

```
while (isLine) {

    CFIndex count = CTTypesetterSuggestLineBreak(typesetter, start, self.frame.size.width);
    if (count <= 0) {
        isLine = NO;
        break;
    }
    currentline ++;
    CTLineRef justifyline = CTTypesetterCreateLine(typesetter, CFRangeMake(start, count));
    if (start + count >= lettercount) {

        justifyline = CTTypesetterCreateLine(typesetter, CFRangeMake(start, count)); 
    }
    else {
        CTLineRef line = CTTypesetterCreateLine(typesetter, CFRangeMake(start, count));        
        justifyline = CTLineCreateJustifiedLine(line, 0, self.frame.size.width);
        CFRelease(line);

    }

    CTLineGetTypographicBounds(justifyline, &ascent, &descent, &leading);
    float lineheight = ascent + descent + leading;
    CFArrayRef runArray = CTLineGetGlyphRuns(justifyline);
    for (CFIndex runIndex = 0; runIndex < CFArrayGetCount(runArray); runIndex++)
    {
        // Get FONT for this run
        CTRunRef run = (CTRunRef)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(runArray, runIndex);
        CTFontRef runFont = CFDictionaryGetValue(CTRunGetAttributes(run), kCTFontAttributeName);
        //NSLog(@"GlyphCount= %d",(int)CTRunGetGlyphCount(run));
        // for each GLYPH in run
        for (CFIndex runGlyphIndex = 0 ; runGlyphIndex < CTRunGetGlyphCount(run) ; runGlyphIndex++) 
        {
            // get Glyph & Glyph-data


            CFRange thisGlyphRange = CFRangeMake(runGlyphIndex, 1);
            CGGlyph glyph;
            CGPoint position;
            CTRunGetGlyphs(run, thisGlyphRange, &glyph);
            CTRunStatus state = CTRunGetStatus(run);
            if (state == kCTRunStatusRightToLeft) {
                NSLog(@"rtl");
            }
            CTRunGetPositions(run, thisGlyphRange, &position);



            position = CGPointMake(position.x, self.frame.size.height + position.y - (100 * currentline));
            NSLog(@"x %f y %f",position.x,position.y);
            // Render it
            {
                CGFontRef cgFont = CTFontCopyGraphicsFont(runFont, NULL);

                CGAffineTransform textMatrix = CTRunGetTextMatrix(run);
                CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, textMatrix);
                CGContextSetFont(context, cgFont);
                CGContextSetFontSize(context, CTFontGetSize(runFont));
                switch (runGlyphIndex) {
                    case 4:
                        CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1, 0.0, 0.0, 1);
                        break;

                    default:
                        CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1);
                        break;
                }               


                CGContextShowGlyphsAtPositions(context, &glyph, &position, 1);

                CFRelease(cgFont);
            }
        }
        CFRelease(runFont);
    }




    start+=count;


}
```

i want to handle glyph by glyph and when glyph is shown on last line, it's shows on left side of page.

Comment: You should edit your question rather than putting this in an answer

Comment: You're highlighting the fourth glyph of every run in red? Do you really mean that? Or do you want to highlight the original text (CFAttributedString)? This code feels very fragile.

Comment: No this is sample not release code , i using paragraph and it's ok and i create very well right to left paragraph but i want to manage glyph to change color of 1 or more glyph , and i meet this problem i use attributedstring but can't handle all of my want

Comment: The another problem for paragraph is suggest height for arabic paragraph i get CTLine height and it's ok but sometimes 1 or more word is missing because calcuate of array of CTLine objets is one less than lines

Comment: I'd have to see the example of what you mean here. The most common cause of truncation is that your original `CTFrame` was too small. BTW, I often like to do my layout code in English first, just to make sure it works correctly in the easiest possible way, and then convert to more complicated languages like Arabic. I often find that what I think is a right-to-left problem is really just a simple bug in my layout code. (Keep in mind that Apple has done a lot of work on correct language layout, so if you're doing "normal" layout it's unlikely to be a Core Text bug.)